# Quartus Stack Overflow on quartus_map.exe while compiling

Tags: vhdl, stack-overflow, quartus

while compiling my VHDL VGA-Project Quartus give me the following response:

```
[Error-Message while compiling PRoject][1]
```

In report i could find the following informations:

Problem Details
Error:

```
*** Fatal Error: Stack Overflow
Module: quartus_map.exe
Stack Trace:
    0xc9dbb: vrfx_add_to_extractor_migration_report + 0x1e00b (synth_vrfx)
    0xca52a: vrfx_add_to_extractor_migration_report + 0x1e77a (synth_vrfx)
    0xca52a: vrfx_add_to_extractor_migration_report + 0x1e77a (synth_vrfx)
    ....100 times the same

End-trace


Executable: quartus_map
Comment:
None

System Information
Platform: windows64
OS name: Windows 7
OS version: 6.2

Quartus II Information
Address bits: 64
Version: 14.1.0
Build: 186
Edition: Web Edition
```

The informations from the internet to this issue is rare.

The reaseon what I am thinking is my intention to draw Text on VGA with FPGA and long arrays with the information of the shape of a char.
Each char (about 100) is containing a 80x2 2d array with addition operators for example:

`when '0' => temp := ((4 + X, 4 + Y), (4 + X, 5 + Y), (4 + X, 6 + Y), (4 + X, 7 + Y), (4 + X, 8 + Y), (5 + X, 3 + Y)....`

Everithing work fine when I try to display 2 lines of text over a screen (about 80 chars), but it also give me a warning:

**The depth of a combinational logic is over 6000, which may cause stack overflow.**

Over 2 lines the compiler crashes, and give the error-report.

maybe one solution is to write the position arrays much shorter, but how? Anyone have an idear?

Greetings Martin.

Comment: I guess you have to think about using some pipeline stages in your design. You have 6000 (!) logic levels w/o any register in between! In a good design you should have maybe up to 20!

Comment: If quartus crashes, you should maybe ask this on the Intel/Alters forum. With respect to your code.. Where is it? The small snippet you show already indicates there is something not quite right with your programming style.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply generating too much combinational storage. There are two problems here :

1. nothing is clocked, so you are generating a huge mass of combinational logic. You will need to learn about synchronous design and clocked processes. I don't want to try teaching that here.
2. You are storing every move (bit in bitmapped graphics, vertex in vertex graphics) here, which is vastly expensive. Go back to the way text was handled before bitmapped graphics became practical at reasonable cost : to a character generator.

The insight (or artificially imposed constraint) here is that every "A" you draw looks the same; therefore you  can reuse the vertices required to draw it.

```
type CHAR_SET is ('A','B','C','1','2','3'); 
-- you may find a suitable character set like ASCII or LATIN-1 already declared in library STANDARD

type ARRAY_CHAR is array (67 downto 0, 1 downto 0) of integer;     
--defines how to draw a single character, relative to its own origin
type ARRAY_CHAR_SET is array (CHAR_SET) of ARRAY_CHAR;     
--Character Generator, defines how to draw every character
constant CHARACTER_SET : ARRAY_CHAR_SET := ( ...);
-- or signal ... more than one CHARACTER_SET would allow more fonts 
type ARRAY_TEXT is array (natural range <>) of CHAR_SET;  
-- for each position on screen, defines which character to draw. For a character set with less than 256 chars, this needs only one byte per character.

function DRAW_CHAR (location) return ARRAY_CHAR is
    variable Char : CHAR_SET;
begin
    -- lookup which char to draw
    Char := ARRAY_TEXT(location); 
    -- offset its origin to the on-screen location
    return OFFSET_ORIGIN(location, CHARACTER_SET(Char));
end DRAW;
```

Comment: Hello Brain, i improve my timing and you totally right, it work. Thank you for opening my eyes. Greetings, Martin.